# facebook sdk not working properly for iOS8

Tags: facebook, ipad, authentication, sdk, landscape

for an **iPad** in **Landscape** orientation,**Facebook** **login browser page** is not orienting in Landscape mode.I have used facebook sdk-3.17 ver.

Kindly help me to solv this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by sdk?

Comment: he means the facebook sdk i guess....

Comment: u r right...i meant Facebook SDK(SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT KIT)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved by integrating new facebook sdk 3.18 ver.

Comment: I only see an JS SDK 2.1 where did you find 3.18?

Comment: I have downloaded facebook SDKs from developer site.